# Changing values in an array

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, multidimensional-array, double

Ok, so here are my codes (main method and method I'm trying to call)
I want my method "rotateRR" to basically take the value from board[0] and put it on [1] and keep doing that for that single row. For example:

old array -> [1][2][3][4][5] to become [5][1][2][3][4] <- what new array should look like.

but after I call my method, I put my regular input which should be "1 rr", but it returns the same array. I need to return the updated array from rotateRR method, but it doesn't let me add a return statement.

public class Numbrosia {
    static int [][] board = new int[5][5];

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    Scanner scan = null;

    try{
        scan = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;

    }

    for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < board.length; j++){
            board[i][j] = scan.nextInt();

        }
    }


    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    while (true){
    showBoard();

    System.out.println("What's your move?"); 
    int rowOrCol = input.nextInt();
    String action = ("");
    action = input.nextLine();

    if (action.equals(rowOrCol + " rr")){
        rotateRR(board);
        System.out.println("The new board looks like: ");
                    //Im guessing I should put something here?
         }

    }
```

}

```
public static void showBoard(){
    for(int row = 0; row < board.length; row++){
        for(int col = 0; col < board.length; col++){
            System.out.print(board[row][col] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println(" ");

        }



}

//METHODS 

public static void rotateRR (int [][] board){ 
    int[] temp = board[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length + 1; i++){
        board[i] = board[i+1];
        }
    board[board.length + 1] = temp;
    }
//Its not letting me add a "return" type, tells me it is a syntax error on and an invalid type
```

Comment: `Its not letting me add a "return" type` -- Yes, it won't.  It's a `void` function, after all.

Comment: @user3288606 Does my answer satisfy your doubt?

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with the method is that it's not even doing what you described as the functionality:

```
public static void rotateRR (int [][] board){ 
    int[] temp = board[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length + 1; i++){
        board[i] = board[i+1];
    }
    board[board.length + 1] = temp;
}
```

Should be changed to:

```
public static void rotateRR (int [][] board){ 

    // Saves the last entry of board, because 
    // each entry should be shifted to the right
    int[] temp = board[board.length - 1];

    // Here you should only run till board.length - 2, because
    // if you add 1 to i for accessing the next entry
    // you can maximal access the entry with number board.length - 1
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length - 1; i++){
        board[i] = board[i+1];
    }

    // Set the first entry to temp
    board[0] = temp;
}
```

So after that method your array you inserted as a parameter is changed the way you described above. Notice that you don't need a return type, since the change affects the original array (keyword call-by-reference).

Answer (score 0):

You have made the function `void` therefore you cannot return anything from it. So what you need to do is change it from void to something like char * and then return the associated char * to solve your problem

Read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html for any further doubts.

Comment: So I changed the header of the method to "public static int [] rotateRR (int [][] board){ " and added a return type. I also changed on how I called my method to "System.out.println(rotateRR(board));"

Its still not updating my array though, its not even saying the "The new board looks like" 

:\

Comment: That seems to be another problem. But if you want to pass variables between functions this is how you can pass, (also given in the oracle docs link) and as for this problem, look over your code once again there must be some problem in it

Comment: board.length + 1 -> ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Answer (score -1):

Change this:

> public static void showBoard()

to this

> public static return-type showBoard()